# Real Analysis Folland Problem 48, product measures

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $X = Y = \mathbb{N}$, $\mathcal{M} = \mathcal{N} = 2^{\mathbb{N}}$, $\mu = v = $ counting measure. Define $f(m,n) = 1$ if $m = n$, $f(m,n) = -1$ if $m = n + 1$, and $f(m,n) = 0$ otherwise. Then $\int |f| d(\mu\times v) = \infty$, and $\int\int f d\mu d v$ and $\int\int f d v d\mu$ exist and are unequal.

proof:
$\int |f|d(\mu\times v) = (\mu\times v)\left(\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}\{(n,n),(n+1,n)\}\right)$. Let $\{A_n\times B_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ be a sequence of rectangles covering $\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}\{(n,n),(n+1,n)\}$, then $\{A_n\times B_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ covers $\mathbb{N}$ and hence $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\mu(A_n\times B_n) = \infty$. This implies that $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\mu(A_n)v(B_n) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\mu(A_n)\mu(B_n) \geq \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\mu(A_n\cap B_n) = \infty$$ Since $\mu(A_n\cap B_n)\in \{0\}\cup [1,\infty] \forall n\in\mathbb{N}$. Therefore, $$\int|f|d(\mu\times v) = \inf\{\infty\} = \infty$$

I am confused on the last part where $\int|f|d(\mu\times v) = \inf\{\infty\}$, can anyone provide some reasoning here, note the proof is not complete.

Now to complete the proof (sort of):

$\int\int f(m,n) d\mu(m)dv(n)$; for the inner integral for fixed $n$, we want to know the counting measure $m$ such that $f(m,n) = 1_{\{n\}}(m) - 1_{\{n+1\}}(m)$, and hence $$\int f(m,n) d\mu(m) = \mu(\{n\}) - \mu(\{n+1\}) = 0$$ This implies that $$\int\int f(m,n)d\mu(m)dv(n) = 0$$

$\int\int f(m,n) dv(n)d\mu(m)$; for the innter integral for fixed $m$, we want to know the counting measure of $n$ such that $f(m,n) = 1_{\{m\}}(n) - 1_{\{m-1\}}(n)$, and hence $$\int f(m,n) dv(n) = v(\{m\}) - v(\{m-1\}) = 0$$

In the problem it states that these two integrals are not equal but seems to me they will both be 0? Any suggestions or comments here are greatly appreciated.

Comment: It's much easier than all that. What is $\mu\times\nu(\{(n,m)\}$?

Comment: I am not sure we only used that type of notation in theorem 2.36, could you provide a proof or beginning of how you would do it?

Comment: I'd begin the proof by finding $\mu\times\nu(\{(n,m)\})$.

Comment: Ok, a hint. What is $\mu\times\nu(A\times B)$?

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich I am still lost on your hint do you think you could provide a beginning of the solution, and then I am sure I can go from there

Comment: You can't even tell me what $\mu\times\nu(A\times B)$ is? If you answer that then that tells you what $\mu\times\nu$ of the single point $(n,m)$ is...

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich $\mu\times v(A\times B) = \mu(A)\times v(B)$?

Comment: Right. That's why it's called the product measure. Now: Given a point $(n,m)$ in the product space in the current problem, what $A$ and $B$ make $\{(n,m)\}=A\times B$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, notice that $ |f| = 1 $ when $ m = n$. Since $ \mu \times \nu( \{m, n\}) = 1 $, so that $\int|f|d(\mu \times \nu) \geq \sum_{m = n} 1 = \infty $. On the other hand, $\int f^{n} d\mu = 0 \ \forall n$ so that $\int \int f d\mu d\nu = 0$. And $\int f_{m} d\nu = 1 $ when $ m = 1 $ and $\int f_{m} d\nu = 0 $ for all other $ m $ so that $ \int \int f d\nu d\mu = 1 $.